# Haskell monad state desugar

Tags: haskell

To study the details of the State monad, I'm trying to desugar :

I pasting versions of which I was able to create with the help of Forum Members.

I want to make sure that my line of thought  is correct:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> State s a
```

---

```
 foo = do
      a <-get
      put(a+1)

foo =
  get >>= \a->
  put (a+1)


2. foo= get >>= \a->put(a+1)
   2.1 get = State (\s->(s,s))
   2.2 put a = State(\_->((), a+1)

3. foo= State (\s->(s,s)) >>= \a->State(\_->((), a+1)

4. foo= State (\s0 -> let (a,s1)=runState( State(\s->(s,s)) s0
                               in runState ((\a->State(\_->((),a+1) a) s1

5. foo= State (\s0 -> let (a,s1)=(\s->(s,s)) s0
                               in runState ((\a->State(\_->((),a+1) a) s1

6. foo= State (\s0 -> let (a,s1)=(s0,s0)  -- a=s0 i s1=s0
                               in runState ((\a->State(\_->((),a+1) a) s1

7. foo= State (\s0 ->  runState ((\a->State(\_->((),a+1) s0) s1

8. foo= State (\s0 ->  runState ((State(\_->((),s0+1) ) s1

9.foo= State (\s0 -> ( \_->((),s0+1) 

10.foo= State (\s0 -> ((),s0+1)


11. runState  foo 0

12. runState (State(\s0->((),s0+1) 0

13 . (\s0->((),s0+1) 0
```

is it correct? :)

Comment: You should really have edited your original question instead of deleting it and posting this one. It's generally confusing to other users when we see "new" questions that look so much like ones we remember having seen.

Comment: Perhaps it will help to observe that `state = State`, hence `runState (state f) = runState (State f) = f`.

Comment: and `runState (state $ \st -> (st,st)) s` = `(\st -> (st,st)) s` = `(s,s)` so `x = s` and `s' = s` - now you can replace this in then next `runState (state ...) ` expression and observe that `runState (state (\s -> ...)) s'` s just `(\s -> ..) s` again

Comment: also note that you did not replace your `a` when you did *desugar* `foo` - look carefully `a` is really `st`!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post with almost exactly this example: http://www.vaibhavsagar.com/blog/2016/06/17/haskell-state/.

If we define `(>>=)` as

```
  (>>=) (State sa) fn =
    State (\s0 -> let (a, s1)  = sa s0
                      State sb = fn a
                  in sb s1)
```

The desugaring is then

```
    do i <- get; put (i+1)
 == get >>= \i -> put (i+1)
 == State (\s -> (s, s)) >>= \i -> State (\_ -> ((), i+1))
```

Which we can simplify by the definition of `(>>=)`:

```
    (>>=) (State (\s -> (s,s))) (\i -> State (\_ -> ((), i+1))) =
      State (\s0 -> let (a, s1)  = (\s -> (s,s)) s0
                     -- (a, s1)  = (s0, s0)
                        State sb = (\i -> State (\_ -> ((), i+1))) a
                     --       sb = (\_ -> ((), s0+1))
                    in sb s1)
                     -- ((), s0+1)
 == State (\s0 -> ((), s0+1))
 == State (\i  -> ((), i+1))
```

Finally, we have

```
    exec (State (\i -> ((), i+1))) 0
 == snd $ runState (State (\i -> ((), i+1))) 0
 == snd $ (\i -> ((), i+1)) 0
 == snd $ ((), 1)
 == 1
```

Comment: My pleasure :). I'd appreciate it if you would accept this answer.